# single value getJSON from php to into a JavaScript variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to create a JavaScript variable to compare to another variable.

- One of those variables comes from a php file. So i created a simple php array and used `json_encode($array)` to convert it to json.
- Using ajax/getJSON, how do I grab that value, put it in a variable, and use it for logical testing?

I've been seeing some examples of getJSON but they are all complex arrays where mine is just a single value. Thanks

Comment: What does the JSON data look like that you are returning?

Comment: use success callback function of $.getJSON method

Comment: {"0":"abc123","CLIENT":"abc123"}

Answer (score 2):

```
$.getJSON('yoururl.php', function(json_data){
   var compare_me = json_data.key // key is the name of the json key name
});
```

Comment: thanks. I added alert(compare_me); and i got an alert box with "undefined"

Comment: @Gio did you add `var compare = json_data.CLIENT;` ?

Comment: Nope... I'm well versed in php/html/css/sql, etc but I'm in the beginning stages of JavaScript and jQuery. Your suggestion worked.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('url_of_oyu_file.php', function(responseText){
   var json_var = JSON.parse(responseText); //Convert the string into object.
   if(json_var.val = value_to_compare){
     //Do Stuff...
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP

your-file.php

```
<?php
 echo json_encode(array('value' => 1));
 exit;
?>
```

Try this

```
$.get('your-file.php', function(data){
 if (data.value === value_to_compare) {
   // Do stuff
 }
}, 'json');
```